# cakephp check multiple tables

Tags: cakephp

I am getting a list of Rate information from the database with conditions. However I wish to add another condition of minimum Stay if the date range has a date in it and rateID form another table called minimum stay. The Rate table already has a min stay but on certain dates I want to over ride this if the date falls within the date range I pass.

I am new to cakephp so I am unsure how to check the minStay table for dates in the date range. Then get the largest minStay and the add it to the condition.

Default minStay in Rate table is 1

Here is the data in the minStay table:

date:31-10-2011 rateID:21 minStay:2
date:1-11-2011 rateID:21 minStay:3

Results: If date range is 31-10-2011 to 2-11-2011 / 2 nights then no results. If 3 nights or more then result.

I hope I have explaind that correctly.

Variable containing the date range is $todays

```
        $conditions = array(
                'Rate.enabled'=>1,'Rate.is_corporate'=>$is_corporate, 'Rate.minimum_stay <='=>$days, 
                'Rate.valid_from < '=>$date_start,'Rate.valid_to >'=>$date_end,
                'OR'=>array('Rate.maximum_stay'=>0,'Rate.maximum_stay >='=>$days)
        );

        $order = 'Rate.list_no';
        $this->Rate->contain('Room.id','Room.title','Room.max_adults','Room.max_children');
        $rates = $this->Rate->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions,'order'=>$order));
```

Comment: You should use the fields option instead of contain to select the fields you want, also you may use contain to use another model if the association are present. If no association in place you may do them on-the-fly or do a force join. can you post the exact condition you want to add?? using cakephp style like Model.something = Model2.somethingElse

Comment: I have the association in the models. I am struggling with the conditions. I want to get records from Rate table with extra conditions on the minimum stay from a new table called minStay to what is above. Something like ('Rate.minimum_stay <='=>$days OR     array('minStay.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date_start,$date_end)) and minStay.minimum_stay < =>$days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understood what you want to do, if not please comment.

To do that you need to do somthing like this (assuming you have something like has many MinStay)

```
    $conditions = array(
            'Rate.enabled'=>1,'Rate.is_corporate'=>$is_corporate, 'Rate.minimum_stay <='=>$days, 
            'Rate.valid_from < '=>$date_start,'Rate.valid_to >'=>$date_end,
            'OR'=>array('Rate.maximum_stay'=>0,'Rate.maximum_stay >='=>$days),
            'AND' => array('OR'=> array('minStay.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date_start,$date_end)),
                 'minStay.minimum_stay <' =>$days )
    );

    $order = 'Rate.list_no';
    $fields = array ('Room.id','Room.title','Room.max_adults','Room.max_children');
    $rates = $this->Rate->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions,'order'=>$order, 'fields'=> $fields));
```

I think that will do it, hope it works for you

Comment: Yes, I want to included another table that if they are records in it for the date range then it will check to see is date range bigger than the minimum stay all. This looks right. Is that what it is doing? Thanks

Comment: If they are records in the minStay table then I dont want to take account of the Rate.minimum_stay but use the new one. If no records for that Rate and those dates that use the default Rate.minimum_stay